# What is the correct order in reading the Naruto manga series?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

I just want to know what is the order for reading the *Naruto* manga, excluding the anime, since there are various ones.

So, what order should I follow in reading them?

Comment: The mangas are serialised according to chapters do you mean the light novels and side mangas? Otherwise you begin at Naruto and then Naruto Shippuden and apparently Naruto is currently being translated in colour version as well.

Comment: I wanna read the side mangas and the light novels too. I just wanted to where they intertwined with the main manga chapters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its only the manga series, then the reading order would be according to the release date:

- *Naruto* (**72 Volumes**)
- *Naruto: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring* (**1 Volume**)
- *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations* (**On-going**)

A Redditor also [posted](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/41y25k/i_made_a_naruto_reading_guide_and_timeline/) a chronological order guide including the light novels, movies, side stories, etc. You can check it out [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ZzPJXMxlFSLe-6DbZXJB75ria2kETtlwGDbA-IZG8Y/edit#gid=0). Not included in that guide are the *Itachi Shinden* books which details the events leading to and during the Uchiha clan's massacre by Itachi.